# I'm creating a password generator but I don't know why it doesn't work

Tags: python, passwords, generator

Basically I'm new to python and I'm using python 3 to try and create a password generator just for fun but I keep running into an issue. When I try the following code in Pydroid 3 it works as intended, which is to create a mixed character (symbols, upper and lower case letters and numbers) password that has a lenght determined by the user, but when I run it on Pycharm I only get 1 character despite saying I want more than 1. Does anyone know the problem?

```
import random
import string
import pyfiglet

print(pyfiglet.figlet_format('Password Generator!\n', font="digital"))

length = int(input('How many characters long do you want the password to be? '))
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
numbers = range(0, 10)
specialchar = list(string.punctuation)
char = ('alfa', 'num', 'char')
pw = []
passw = ''

while length > 0:
    if random.choice(char) == 'alfa':
        x = str(random.choice(alphabet))
        pw.append(x)
        passw = ''.join(x)
        length -= 1
    elif random.choice(char) == 'num':
        x = str(random.choice(numbers))
        pw.append(x)
        passw = ''.join(x)
        length -= 1
    else:
        x = str(random.choice(specialchar))
        pw.append(x)
        passw = ''.join(x)
        length -= 1


def randomupper(c):
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        return c.upper()
    return c.lower()


password = ''.join(map(randomupper, passw))
print(f'Your randomly generated password is: {password}')
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: This program must be different to the one that worked. Perhaps you meant: password = ''.join(map(randomupper, pw))

Answer (score 0):

change this line and it will work

```
password = ''.join(map(randomupper, pw))
```

with `passw = ''.join(x)` you iteratively add one char inside `x` with empty char`''` to the variable passw, and it will end up having just one char inside it when the loop ends.
but `pw.append(x)` add the char inside `x` to the end of the `pw` and increase its size.
so simply when you use `passw` instead of `pw`, you will see only last char that created inside your loop.

Comment: It's helpful to explain *why*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sure, I will add some explanation

Answer (score 0):

It's because the string `passw` just appends the latest character `x` to itself. It doesnt interact with the list `pw` at all. Having both `pw` and `passw` is not needed instead use `pw += x` in each of the if statements which appends to the string directly and then change your final line to 
`password = ''.join(map(randomupper, pw))`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is the line `passw = ''.join(x)` which erases the password and replaces it with just the last generated character.

Some other things to improve:

- to run a loop a fixed number of times, `for i in range(length)` makes sure the loop is executed exactly `length` times without the need to initialize, update and test a variable
- code like `pw.append(x)` that is the same for every case of the if-tests can be put outside
- your variable pw is already a string, so `passwd = ''.join(pw)` just copies the string

The updated code:

```py
import random
import string

length = int(input('How many characters long do you want the password to be? '))
alphabet = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
numbers = range(0, 10)
specialchar = list(string.punctuation)
char = ('alfa', 'num', 'char')
passw = ''

for i in range(length):
    if random.choice(char) == 'alfa':
        x = str(random.choice(alphabet))
    elif random.choice(char) == 'num':
        x = str(random.choice(numbers))
    else:
        x = str(random.choice(specialchar))
    passw.append(x)

def randomupper(c):
    if random.random() > 0.5:
        return c.upper()
    return c.lower()

password = ''.join(map(randomupper, passw))
print(f'Your randomly generated password is: {password}')
```

Comment: I really like this approach where you use for loops instead of my giant while loop. I admit that I though about using for loops in the beggining but I changed to a while loop while I was writting the code and now I see that for loops was the optimized way. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A for-loop is quicker to understand. You immediately see what it does. With the while-loop you have the check all the places the variable is updated and make sure there is nowhere an error.

Answer (score 0):

I've read all the replies so far and you people helped me a lot, thanks! I realized that there's a mistake in the  passw = ''.join(x) statement which should be  passw = ''.join(pw)